# How to solve $x^{-2} + x^{-3} = \dfrac{x^3 + x^2}{4x^6}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

For online school I was given the equation $$x^{-2} + x^{-3} = \frac{x^3 + x^2}{4x^6}.$$ The problem lies in the addition of the bases, as I do not know how to solve that. Could you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/5023#5023) is a MathJax tutorial.  Consider multiplying both sides by $x^6$

Comment: Clue: multiply both sides by $x^3$.

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $x^4$ leads to a quadratic equation; do you know how to solve quadratic equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$x^{-2} + x^{-3} = \dfrac{x^3 + x^2}{4x^6}$$

$$x^4+x^3=\frac{1}{4}(x^3+x^2)$$

$$x^4+\frac34 x^3-\frac14 x^2=0$$

$$x^2(4x^2+3x-1)=0$$

However, since $x=0$ is not a solution (it is in the denominator of the original equation), we can divide out by $x$ to get

$$4x^2+3x-1=0$$

This is a simple quadratic equation, can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can! Thank you so much